# Unicode in terminal on Ubuntu vs Macos

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, unicode

I'm facing an odd issue; a piece of python code from "Learn python the hard way" executed on MacOS and Ubuntu 16.04 gives me quite different visual results.

Sorry for attaching screenshots to demonstrate the issue ...

[image: ubuntu]
[image: macos]

As you can see for some languages on Ubuntu the terminal doesn't render the unicode characters (giving the little squares instead) and I'm trying to figure out why

Comment: What terminal emulator? It's probably the font missing.

Comment: What font are you using in the terminal? Can you post the code?

Comment: That's uxterm, and as I haven't done any tweaking I assume it uses what's defined in /etc/X11/app-defaults/UXTerm ...

Answer (score 2):

If it's uxterm on both systems, and using the same font selection, the other place to look is at the locale tables which could be different between the two systems.

xterm checks the system's tables at startup, and may use its own tables if the system's got too many problems.  The choice is controlled by the [**`mkWidth`**](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:mkWidth) resource.

For example, in the bug report [FreeBSD #219800](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=219800#c39), I made a table showing the number of incorrectly coded characters for a few different systems, including OSX and Linux.  Now... if the Ubuntu tables passed the initial test, but had problems in less-used dialects, while OSX did not pass the test and xterm chose to use its own table (which happened to work better with the font), then you could get a difference like that.

Just looking at the screenshots, the missing characters appear to be codepoints using *combining characters*.  That's especially relevant to locale support since the additional characters after the base character would be reported by `wcwidth` as zero-width.

Comment: Thomas, thanks for the response.  I don't use uxterm on Mac, I don't think, it's whatever OS/X throws you when you type *terminal*.  I will read your bug-report and see if I can make sense of that :)

Comment: `Terminal.app` has its own quirks, but usually has better font support than XQuartz.  However -- see the table -- Apple's updates for locale support aren't on the same schedule as Debian/Ubuntu/whatever.